# How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, shortcuts

Somehow I went to open a shortcut and Windows couldn't find the target but instead of pointing the shortcut to the `.exe` it pointed the `.lnk` file handler to the `.exe`, so now all my `.lnk` files are trying to be opened by the borderlands game.

What's going on?

I'm guessing I can do it by resetting the `.lnk` entry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, but I don't know what to set it to.

Comment: [hunkid0ry's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/124289/432863) fixed the problem immediately -- no reboot, no logout/login -- and is one step

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open `regedit` from the Start Menu (You can also invoke the file using Run command).
Navigate to the following registry branch:

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk`

Click on the arrow to expand it and delete the sub-key named `UserChoice`.
Exit from Registry Editor.

After this do a reboot.

Comment: You can even restart explorer.exe instead of rebooting.

Comment: This answer is correct if it was only the user's preference that was affected. Otherwise, the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk registry key will need to be rebuilt, as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: I navigated to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk" please note the \ in the end. This is what I see [link to three screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qho3af8dxml1jy4/AACHE_93OeN-L54Vc-GSKLIBa?dl=0). Should I delete allt hat are not Named "(Default)"?

Comment: There is a similar question on the Microsoft KB and their solution doesn't work! This answer is better than theirs! =)

Comment: Or just log off and then back in. No reboot is required for this.

Answer (score 28):

Follow these steps to save the Registry code below into a `.reg` file then import it into the Registry:

1. Open Notepad
2. Copy and paste the Registry code below into the Notepad window
3. Save the file to your Desktop with the name **fixshortcuts.reg**
4. On your Desktop open **fixshortcuts.reg** and merge the file into the Registry
5. Log off and back on to make the changes take effect

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;LNK file association fix for Windows Vista.
;Updated on April 24, 2007

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
@="lnkfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""
"Command"=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
@="Shortcut"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000001
"FriendlyTypeName"="@shell32.dll,-4153"
"NeverShowExt"=""
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\CLSID]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\IconHandler]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk\UserChoice]
```

Comment: That is amazing. You are amazing. It worked like a charm. (After I logged off and on again).

Comment: Got the message

"The specified file is not a registry script. You can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor."

I createt a txt file in C:/Users/jl/ and pasted the code and renamed the file to .reg

Comment: You saved my day !

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 12):

The extension `.lnk` is associated with the Lnkfile which is more commonly known as a Shortcut.

To repair the misassociation, open a Command Prompt and type:

```
assoc.lnk=lnkfile
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you should be good to go.

Comment: You the star for the day 100% worked for me

Comment: That worked instantly to repair damage left behind by malware

Comment: This is a great tip, I'd buy you a beer/coffee if I could.

Answer (score 8):

A system restore to before the problem started will fix it, and likely any other file association changes.

Thank god for system restore points. I don't know a direct fix, but I'm back up and running.

If you can't fix it with a scalpel, try a sledgehammer.

Comment: If you can't fix it with a sledgehammer, you're not hitting it hard enough!

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have found on several places (like [here](http://www.malwarecrypt.com/showthread.php?t=105) or [there](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21506733-Vista-Lost-LOT-of-Shortcuts-LNK-and-File-Associations)), you can fix this with a registry operation.

- Create a new text file
- Paste the following inside

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk] @="lnkfile"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellEx]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellEx{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
>   @="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellEx{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
>   @="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellEx{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
>   @="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellEx{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
>   @="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellNew]
>   "Command"="rundll32.exe
>   appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere %1"

- Save the file as "Something.reg"
- Double-click the file

---

I can't guarantee that it will fix your problem (since I don't have it myself), but having tested this on my current computer, I can tell you at least that this is harmless (and reading the keys which are modified, it seems to indeed restore the behavior for .lnk extensions).