# All .lnk files always open with Wordpad

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-windows-7)
>   [How do you associate the .exe file extension with a program in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/354771/how-do-you-associate-the-exe-file-extension-with-a-program-in-windows)
>   [Accidentally caused all .exe programs to open in Notepad](https://superuser.com/questions/364251/accidentally-caused-all-exe-programs-to-open-in-notepad)

My friend e-mailed me a .lnk file, and I chose to open it with Wordpad.  I think the check box for 'always open using this program' was checked, because all of my links now are opened using word pad.  Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Windows Vista 64-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways, but only one tends to work:

Go to Start -> Default Programs (on the right or just type it in). Click on Associate a file type or protocol with a program. Scroll down to .lnk and change the program.

If that doesn't work, then take a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172053

Comment: link broken, please update.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. If you have Vista or Windows 7, press *Start* and type in `regedit`. Or, go to the registry editor in any other way.

Open the subfolders for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

- `software`
- `Microsoft`
- `Windows`
- `Current Version`
- `Explorer`
- `fileExts`
- `.lnk`

Here, delete `userchoice` and then reboot.

Comment: Instead of *userchoice* you may see an *OpenWithList* key in which there is *A Wordpad*
and possibly `B <another setting>` and `MRU <another setting>`
Just delete all of these, the changes take effect immediately and fix the fault.