# Accidentally caused all .exe programs to open in Notepad

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you associate the .exe file extension with a program in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/354771/how-do-you-associate-the-exe-file-extension-with-a-program-in-windows)

I wanted to look at a shortcut or .exe file (not sure which, unfortunately) in Notepad, so I opened it right up (Open with ...).

Then I realized that I must have told the computer to *always* open such files with Notepad ... now everything is screwed up.  Can't even figure out how to open the shell.

**How do I undo this?**  Or have I already made a permanent change?

---

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/354771/how-do-you-associate-the-exe-file-extension-with-a-program-in-windows), but I'm not a power user, so I don't understand the answers.  I thought this could be done through the control panel.

To make it more difficult, I'm on a french computer, and using Windows 7 (I think) which I'm not familiar with (always used XP).

Comment: Also similar:  http://superuser.com/questions/210670/all-lnk-files-always-open-with-wordpad   but the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Related solution: http://superuser.com/q/354771/24500

Comment: Run `assoc .exe=exefile` in CMD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I finally found after lots of googling was [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/undo-file-association-for-lnk-extension-to/f13b105e-8ea3-47e4-aeda-66f8fc1e839d):

> What I did to correct.
>
> Clear the association from the first two keys. My fun included a third
>   key named something like user option or user choice(which I deleted).
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk\OpenWithProgids
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk\OpenWithList
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk\user
>   option something

**Note:** I don't know if this is the best way, or if it's safe, or even if the entire problem is fixed.  But as far as I can tell everything seems to be back to normal.

---

**Here's what I did** (as nearly as I can remember) for a non-poweruser:

- click on the start menu, and in the search box type in "regedit"
- open the application that it finds for you
- in the program that opens, follow the path in the above post (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk\OpenWithProgids`)
- delete the key mentioned above
- exit
- restart the computer