# Cannot run regedit to fix registry problems

Tags: regedit

I cannot run regedit or any other exe programs after I used by mistake the command open with windows media center by default. Everything is opening with wmc and I cannot repair anything. please help!

Comment: What happens if you click start, type regedit and press Enter. Does this make WMC open? Personally, I'd remove/disable it http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15530/uninstall-disable-or-remove-windows-7-media-center/ , this will hopefully sort it out as the OS will realise it's not there and hopefully default back

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7) gives you a bunch of examples of how to fix this problem.

Comment: @Karan: The question you proposed as a duplicate is the opposite case (how to replicate the problem, not how to undo it).  Ramhound's link contains some solutions.  I'll propose that as a duplicate.

Comment: @fixer1234: The main reason I proposed that as the 'original' is because it seems to be the question of choice to link to. See all these for example: http://superuser.com/questions/364251/accidentally-caused-all-exe-programs-to-open-in-notepad http://superuser.com/questions/427434/how-to-fix-exe-file-association-in-windows http://superuser.com/questions/915937/all-exe-programs-have-been-replaced-with-notepad-including-command-prompt-and http://superuser.com/questions/789298/incorrect-file-association-for-exe-files-in-windows and so on.

Comment: @fixer1234: I wish we could vote to merge. Often (good) answers are spread out over duplicates. Even if the questions aren't merged, having the answers all grouped together under one heading might make sense, at least in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

This may help mate, seems that the file association for exe files has been changed, as stated in the link below you need a script or reg file to modify the registry for you

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/exe-file-association-windows-7-vista/

Hope this helps buddy