# Fix .lnk file association WITHOUT admin/registry access

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, shortcuts, file-association

I managed to recreate the problems detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/210670/all-lnk-files-always-open-with-wordpad) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/e8631c28-4ce5-43cc-8865-b75fa2255b57/desktop-and-start-program-icon-lnk-file-associations). I tried to use Notepad to open a .lnk file. Now all shorcuts appear as .lnk files, and open in Notepad. This isn't an uncommon problem and there are numerous solutions floating around, including in the thread I linked. Unfortunately, most of them involve using regedit or otherwise modifying the registry. I don't have admin access on this computer (work machine) and registry access has been locked.

Do I have any prayer of fixing this without admin access? Tech support was less than helpful, and it will be weeks before I can see them in person..

This is using Windows 7.

Comment: You can't solve it without access to the registry.

Comment: If it's a work machine then the IT staff HAS to fix it for you, especially if they decided to lock you completely out of regedit.  If it's stopping you from working, then your IT needs to get their butts in gear and come help you sooner rather than later (IMO anyway).

Comment: I work remotely. IT was unable to remote into my machine, and I won't be on our own network in the immediate future. This won't stop me from working, it will just make me less efficient. It sounds like I'm SOL without access to the registry.. bummer.

Comment: You've already got the answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/210674/245848), isn't it? You do not have to be an admin to tune up _Default Programs_.

Comment: @Merzavets, what should I select as the default program for .lnk files, then? Unfortunately there's no option to forget/restore default here..

Comment: Umm, @mobabo, did I misunderstood you?  [Default Programs screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/3pnrh_dtZzePe).
This is Win8 screen, but Win7 has exactly the same.

Comment: @Merzavets, yes, I've accessed that screen and can change the programs associated with each filetype. As you can see in that screenshot, .lnk files are associated with 'unknown program'. My problem is that I associated .lnks with Notepad. I need to get them back to 'unknown program', i.e. the OS, but don't know how to do that from this dialog.