# .lnk files creates as hidden in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I had a problem in my Windows 7 Professional, since when I clicked "New->Shortcut" on the desktop or a folder, nothing would happen. I downloaded the following REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
@="lnkfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
@="Shortcut"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000001
"FriendlyTypeName"="@shell32.dll,-4153"
"IsShortcut"=""
"NeverShowExt"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\CLSID]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\IconHandler]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\piffile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSHFile]
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"29"=-

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lnk]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lnk]
"FileOperationPrompt"="prop:System.ItemTypeText;System.FileOwner;System.Author;System.Title;System.Subject;System.Comment;System.DateModified;System.Link.TargetParsingPath"
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemTypeText"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk\OpenWithProgids]
"lnkfile"=hex(0):
```

Now I can create new shortcuts, but the lnk files I create have the hidden attribute set, and the icons are faded just like any hidden file. What can I do in order to create them as non-hidden?

Comment: Could you please verify what happens you create a LNK file outside of your normal folder, e.g. create a new folder on C:\ and add a shortcut there. Does it also have the hidden attribute set?

Comment: By selecting an item and selecting "create shortcut", the created shortcut isn't hidden. If I use the right click->new->shortcut item, a shortcut is immediately created even if I still don't provide the target: that shortcut is already set as hidden.

Comment: Now this is really funny. I have searched all I could up and down and couldn't come up with anything that even comes close to this error. Do you have any chance to use a restore point before this happens? Given the results of this answer http://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-win7 it might be the only thing that could work. If this is no option the only way would be to use Process Monitor and watch every step Explorer (or other) programs are doing with the new LNK file.

Comment: Unfortunately System Restore is disabled. What about the Process Explorer procedure? Could you explain this? I already downloaded Process Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use McAfee Internet Security?

I had the same issue with my computer - I found that the problem was with McAfee. When turning on real time scanning, any new shortcuts got the hidden attribute, and when rotating a picture with Windows Photo Viewer, the picture was hidden too. After turning off real time scanning in McAfee, everything was okay again.

Check out this topic:

> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/when-ever-i-edit-a-files-properties-such-as-on-a/71774527-6c80-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?page=1&tm=1305828561470#footer

Comment: And... we have a winner!

Following your link, there's a mcafee faq link: http://service.mcafee.com/faqdocument.aspx?id=TS101228

By following these steps the issue is resolved. Thanks anyone who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

For IconPath I have "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-16769" (no quotes).
I do not have

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
>   "29"=-

at all.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations.lnk] gives:

```
FileOperationPrompt    REG_SZ    prop:System.ItemTypeText;System.FileOwner;System.Author;System.Title;System.Subject;System.Comment;System.DateModified;System.Link.TargetParsingPath    FullDetails    REG_SZ    prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemTypeText
```

In all honesty, I have no idea what half of this means, or why any of it would cause the errors you are getting, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it, but that way I lose the icon in che "New" menu and doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Removing "29"=- didn't solve; as for the second block, it seems the same as mine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lorthik: The `=-` means "delete"; if you imported it once, removing the line will have absolutely no effect since the value has already been deleted from registry.

Answer (score 0):

As none of the registry changing has helped, it could be that different program is doing here something with the LNK file. To verify that, download [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Microsoft.

Start it and press CTRL+L to open up the filter and add a filter like this:

[image: Process Monitor filter]

Click *Add* and dismiss the Filter window.

From this time on it will show you any event that is happening in this folder. Switch to Explorer and create the *C:\TEST* folder and you will see that PM will capture these events.

Press CTRL+X inside PM to clear the entire list, go back to Explorer and then right-click inside *C:\TEST* to create a new shortcut.

Don't wonder about the many entries that are created, that's normal. I guess the important information should be on the top and look like this:

[image: Process Monitor result]

As you can see the file is created on my system with no hidden attribute. It will be interesting what happens on your system.

Comment: I did the procedure you described. I'm posting the results (I know it's not much readable... but I couldn't find a better way): http://pastebin.com/Y7MQkrFb

Maybe it could be of interest the .tmp file created?

Comment: Any chance you could save the output directly as PML and upload it somehwere so I can have a detailed look. The CSV is somewhat... hard.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation. Here it is: http://www.easy-share.com/1917555914/Logfile.PML

Comment: @Lorthirk: Thanks for the file, I will grab it ASAP. But please give me some time I'm currently busy assemble my new PC.