# How to define default program to open shortcuts?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-windows-7)

In Windows 7 I have accidentally set OUTLOOK.EXE as the default program to open all Shortcuts.  So now the Outlook icon appears on all my shortcuts, even new ones that I create!   I have no idea of how to undo this silly state of events, for I do not know the name of the Windows program that normally opens shortcuts.  Also, all the programs in my `Start` menu are the same, and so I have no example shortcuts that open properly!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-windows-7
This post looks like the same issue.

Comment: Just answer your own question if you've found out, don't delete it. It'll help other people.

Comment: Or if you're going to delete it, then click the actual "delete" button rather than editing the question into nonsense.