# Stop shortcuts from opening with 7Zip

Tags: shortcuts, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-windows-7)

I accidentally did something strange and now all my Shortcuts (.lnk) are now set to open with 7Zip.

[image: Start menu]

Running it yields the following:

[image: 7Zip cannot open file]

In order to open a program now, I have to right-click on it, goto Properties, "Open File Location" and then run the .exe file.

**How can I make .lnk files open normally again?**

**Edit:** I have tried going into `Default Programs` ("Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations").  I can find .lnk, but I don't know what program to associate it with (I don't even think it's a program).

Comment: See this answer: http://superuser.com/a/277232/101850

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.  I had to reload `Windows Explorer` to get all the icons to update.  I guess this is a dupe then...