# Fixing .lnk files in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, shortcuts

How can I fix `.lnk` file association in Windows 8?

I can see how to do it for Windows 7 ([How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/92869/)), but am not sure if the solution will be the same. I don't want to mess with the registry unless I know it's going to work!

Comment: What program are .lnk files opening with?

Comment: They're currently not associated with any program.

Comment: if you don't want to mess with the registry, try the command line… assoc.lnk=lnkfile & Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the [fix damaged file association in Windows 8](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-asso-fixes-for-windows-8/). Open the [zip and import the .reg file for the lnk](http://www.winhelponline.com/fileasso/lnk_fix_w8.zip).