# shortcuts opening as 7zip files

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip

My brother tried to open a .lnk file with 7zip and now every shortcut tries to open in 7zip, how do i undo this or fix this? I genuinely have no idea what to do or where to start and no one else appears to have had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the UserChoice entry for it in the registry, as already posted here:

[How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-windows-7)

Comment: Hi Afaan, the usual way to indicate duplicates is to flag as duplicate.