# Shortcuts open fine in Explorer but not in cmd.exe

Tags: windows

On other similar systems typing foo.lnk in a cmd.exe box will invoke the link (open what it points to) but for whatever reason on one particular system, it opens the contents of the .lnk file itself in Wordpad (which seems to come from from `HKCR\*\Shell\(Default)` which has the value `Wordpad`.)

I've searched the web and read through threads like [How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file)  in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/92869/how-to-reset-shortcuts-lnk-file-in-windows-7) but none of the solutions there helped.

`assoc .lnk` shows `.lnk=lnkfile` already.

`HKCR\.lnk\(Default)` shows `lnkfile`.

I've also tried clearing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk`.

But the problem still persists.

Below is some info from the registry. Feel free to ask for any additional info.
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*](https://gist.github.com/gordon-fish/5c94efe458837279b2a67c3f14eb9022)
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile](https://gist.github.com/gordon-fish/e8865e3fa5d1557a4b66e7a61ba38082)

Thanks for any help.